# Eclipse Always Debugs Project Trunk

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-juno, trunk

I have a project I checked out with svn at work. It has the following associated with it in Package Explorer view of Eclipse:

```
project[trunk]
project-adhoctest[trunk/adhoctest]
project-jar[trunk/gazelle]
project-war[trunk/webapp]
```

Now I have a file in the project jar directory that I have put a breakpoint in. What is weird is that when debugger is launched, it always goes to the project[trunk]. This is really bad because I need to debug changes I make, not the trunk I checked out, but in project-jar.

The only other details is that I used maven to build dependencies when I imported this project. But, to make sure I did that right, I deleted everything and checked out this project again. Still same problem. I goggled quite a bit and asked others at work what could be going wrong, but haven't found a fix yet.

I use Eclipse Juno, 4.2.2

Thanks, 
GeekyOmega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the build path was wrong, for me. It was looking at the entire workplace and choosing the trunk. When I re-installed eclipse, when I first ran debug, it asked me for the build path. I pointed the build path to the project folder project-jar instead. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to run-->debug configuration and add the branch project in the Source tab